# Setting Server 2008R2 up for ASP.NET with Razor

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net, installation, iis-7.5

I have created a webpage with WebMatrix on my laptop running Windows 7 and IIS7. WebMatrix automatically set up IIS7 so that it can run ASP.NET 4.0 and I haven't done anything further than that.

I'm now trying to set up my Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS7.5 for ASP.NET WebPages using C# with Razor-code. For this I have installed ASP.NET 4.0 and set the application pool to ASP.NET 4.0.

The site can easily be published with WebMatrix, but WebMatrix can't check compatibility and when trying to access a `.cshtml` file, it can't be found.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read through http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/webmatrix-and-aspnet-web-pages-release-docs, and found that the following must be in the Web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

This solves everything :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Razor (or MVC in general, I'm no developer) but what I do know is that you can push the code to your [IIS without having MVC installed](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx) on the server (best as I can tell, Razor code is supposed to have MVC3 installed on the server). Unless I misunderstood your question, you should be able to follow the steps in the link above, and get your site working.

Comment: I already deployed the bin dll's using the publishing-function in WebMatrix. I think the problem lays in that I can't even see my .cshtml files from the webbrowser. It just says "The requested document was not found on this server."

Comment: You may need to check permissions on the folder the site is hosted in IF you have the site sitting somewhere other than c:\inetpub\wwwroot

Comment: Even if fx index.htm can be seen with no problems?

Comment: So, the browser can see the file index.htm in the directory, but it cannot see a .cshtml file in the same directory?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: I just installed the MVC3 package on the server:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4211
Now the server displays clean text, but the text seem to be a error message anyway?:/

Comment: My developer friend tells me this: "Load the page in Kasini (Visual Studio's built-in web server) if the page loads there, but not in IIS, its a problem with routing in IIS. If the page won't load in Kasini either, then he made changes to the RegisterRoutes method, and he'll need to fix it." - Make sense to you?

Comment: First: Thanks for asking a friend! :) I already tried to load the page through VS and WebMatrix on my own development-laptop and here the application runs flawless. So the problem lies in the routing in the IIS. I just dont have an idea about where :/

Comment: Problem solved! I wrote it in an answer :)